# If the Monero started with rCT, would it be needed to have any part of the codebase handling dust?

Tags: ringct, transaction-fees, dust

I mean there is so much code in Monero handling situation that involve any dust. 
Is it just for backward compatibility or would it be needed even if the Monero started with rCT?

I know about 2 types of dust:

1) **dust as an output lower than fee**
As far as I understand it, it just seems unnecessary to call it dust, because the only special thing is that this "dust" can't be sent on it's own, nothing more, right?

2) **dust as some amount that was unmixable before rCT**
If the Monero started with rCT, it would not happen to have this kind of dust, right?

So in the end, if the Monero started now with rCT, it could remove all the dust code, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would indeed not be needed.

For the "below its weight in fee" case, the wallet could just avoid spending those outputs.

Comment: I just wasn't sure. :)